# Changing UIToolBar (appearance) at runtime

Tags: ios

I want to change an UIToolBar at runtime. In it's initial state, is has only one button, when that button is pressed i want it to change it's appearance to show 4 buttons. One of these buttons should cause the first UIToolBar to reappear.

Im seeing two approaches:

1) Have two UIToolBar nibs, and load them as needed.

2) Having all buttons on the first UIToolbar, and hide/show them as needed.

What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would want to see all 4 button at initial launch with only relevant button in enabled state and rest in disabled state. Once I tap on the already enabled button I should see other buttons getting enabled. This is less surprising UI for end user. However, you can also go with #2 mentioned above in which case you might want to add some animation effect for better user experience.

Comment: Didn't even think about it that way. Sounds reasonable thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second approach would be better, because if you want to add more buttons tomorrow, you need to maintain 2 nib files instead of one.

But, think again is creating toolbar in xib file good solution?

I would create custom toolbar extending UIToolbar class and make 2 methods in it:

- -(NSArray*) toolbarButtonsInitial;
- -(NSArray*) toolbarButtonsExtended;

  -toolbarButtonsInitial method returns UIBarButtonItems for initial state

  -toolbarButtonsExtended method returns UIBarButtonItems for second state.

IMHO, this way has several advantages:

- Your xib file doesn't have hidden buttons, or some button above other
  one
- If you need to add or remove some buttons you can do that easily for
  each state
- You can easily reuse this toolbar on other screens and create new
  states if necessary